# Prove a function, defined by integration of a harmonic function, is log-convex

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $u$ be a harmonic function and we define
$$ q(r)=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}u^2(x)\,dx $$

The question is about to prove that $q(r)$ is log-convex, i.e., I want to show $\log q(r)$ is convex function of $\log r$

I compute 
$$ \frac{d^2}{(d\log r)^2} \log q(r) = r^2\frac{q''(r)}{q(r)}+r\frac{q'(r)}{q(r)}-\left(r\frac{q'(r)}{q(r)}\right)^2 $$ 
I was hoping to prove that 
$$ r\frac{q'(r)}{q(r)}\geq\left(r\frac{q'(r)}{q(r)}\right)^2 $$ 
i.e., 
$$r q'(r)\geq q(r)$$
However, unfortunately, I proved the opposite direction...

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: This question is phrased as if it is an exercise. If it isn't an exercise, where did you come across this fact, and was there not a reference that you could look up?

Comment: Yes it is an exercise. above is what I tried...

Comment: If it is an exercise then it is not really on topic for this site (and you should be getting help from the person who assigned this exercise)

Comment: ok...I am prepare an exam so I just find some exercise online to practice. This problem I found on some prof's website but that prof is even in another country...

Comment: Are you sure of that definition? Usually "f(x) is log (or logarithmically) convex" just means: $\log f(x)$ is convex.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused as well but this is what that exercise says... Neither way I can not prove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more or less an exercise, instead of a research problem, which is not suitable for posing on this site.

However, I provide an link for your problem,

http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2010-11/3term/ma110c/HarmonicFunctions.pdf

You could find more information by just google "subharmonic functions", here is an overview
http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Subharmonic_function

There are also nice books in the London Mathematical Society Monographs on subharmonic functions by Hayman et al. , which contains all the desired properties of subharmonic functions.

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother around with this problem. I tried it for a while and can not get it. So I post it here for some help. You mean I can find the answer for this problem in your link?

Comment: You can find both answers to your question in the pdf. This site is usually for real research problem or philosophy of some important results, or references request.